# htmlbox post value with form submit

Tags: jquery, html, plugins, post

i'm using the htmlbox jquery plugin, 
if i submit the form when just having entered some text but not using any of the toolbar buttons, the old data is being submitted instead of the new edited text.
When i hit a toolbarbutton first (to make some text bold for example) the new text IS being submitted.

I see the plugin has get_html and get_text functions: am i supposed to first query the wysiwygeditor before submitting or is there something else i'm missing?

The example given on the plugin-website uses a custom submitmethod, I prefer not having a controllermethod serverside (asp mvc) just for posting one textfield, i prefer posting the complete form using a regular `<input type=submit ..>`

edit: this works as workaround but just feels wrong

```
$('#form').submit(function() { (hb.val(hb.get_html())); });
```

Comment: One cheap way is to simulate a click on the toolbar buttons.

Comment: sounds to me that the the plugin doesn't truly initialize itself until an action has been taken on it. Maybe you are missing an initialization option? When do you initialize the htmlbox? Please post your code...

Answer (score 0):

To use HtmlBox's built-in functions, do this:
Assign the return of htmlbox() to a variable and then call HtmlBox's methods using that variable (e.g. hb_full.get_html(); or any other method). See code example below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var hb_full;
$(document).ready(function(){
        hb_full = $("#htmlbox_full").css("height", "300").css("width", "100%").htmlbox({
            toolbars: [
                [
                    // Cut, Copy, Paste
                    "separator", "cut", "copy", "paste",
                    // Undo, Redo
                    "separator", "undo", "redo",
                    // Bold, Italic, Underline, Strikethrough, Sup, Sub
                    "separator", "bold", "italic", "underline", "strike", "sup", "sub",
                    // Left, Right, Center, Justify
                    "separator", "justify", "left", "center", "right",
                    // Ordered List, Unordered List, Indent, Outdent
                    "separator", "ol", "ul", "indent", "outdent",
                    // Hyperlink, Remove Hyperlink, Image
                    "separator", "link", "unlink", "image"
                ],
                [
                    // Show code
                    "separator", "code",
                            // Formats, Font size, Font family, Font color, Font, Background
                    "separator", "formats", "fontsize", "fontfamily",
                    "separator", "fontcolor", "highlight",
                ],
                [
                    //Strip tags
                    "separator", "removeformat", "striptags", "hr", "paragraph",
                    // Styles, Source code syntax buttons
                    "separator", "quote", "styles", "syntax"
                ]
            ],
            about: true, // "false" to hide About button
            idir: "./img/HtmlBoxImg/",
            icons: "default", //all options: "default", "silk"
            skin: "blue"      //all options: "silver", "blue", "green", "red"
        });
    });

    function getHtmlFromEditor()
    {
        var HtmlFromEditor = hb_full.get_html();
        alert(HtmlFromEditor);
    }
    </script>

    <textarea id="htmlbox_full"></textarea>
<button onclick="getHtmlFromEditor();">Display HTML</button>
```